# PYTHONPATH with directory of libraries?

Tags: python

Lets say i have the following directory tree...

```
. 
+--A
|  +-- X
|    +-- __init__.py
|    +-- x.py
|  +-- Y
|    +-- __init__.py
|    +-- y.py
```

... if I were to add directory `A` (note there is no `__init__.py`) to the PYTHONPATH, would the `X` and `Y` libraries be accessible? If not, is there a way to add `X` and `Y` to the PYTHONPATH via `A` without making `A` a library itself?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? Experimenting and playing with the Python shell is one of the best ways to learn!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `A` to the PYTHONPATH (without it being a library itself) successfully includes `X` and `Y`.

Thanks for the motivation carpetsmoker, i was being lazy :P